# How to avoid writing duplicate values in JSONArray in file

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to write string values in `JSONArray` fetched from `javafx list[values are added in javafx list at the run-time by the user]`. 
But, unfortunately, it is adding the same entry for multiple time which cause the duplicate values in file.

```
public static void DumpValues(String value) throws IOException, ParseException {
    try {
        Map m = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

        // Check if array not exist
        File file1 = new File(FILE_NAME);
        if (file1.length() == 0) {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
            m = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("Data", value);
            ja.add(m);
            jo.put("Array", ja);
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME, false);
            file.append(jo.toString());
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } else {
            // Check if array exist, add values in the array
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(FILE_NAME));
            if (obj == null) {
                System.out.println("ex");
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Array");

            System.out.println("..." +jsonArray.size());     
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
            m = new LinkedHashMap(2);
            m.put("Data", value);
            jsonArray.add(m);
            jo.put("Array", jsonArray);

            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME, false);
            file.append(jo.toString());
            file.flush();
            file.close();     
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(JSONSearching.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I don't understand what it cause to write the the String values multiple time, I just want to add the value a single time.

Comment: How often is that method called? It seems like if you call it twice with the same value, it will add the value to the file twice, which is the behavior you described...

Comment: its only called once "on Drag Exited" on listview, and it is not writing just two values, it is adding multiple entries. Here is the output Sample: {"Array":[{"Data":"Doctor"},{"Data":"Doctor"},{"Data":"Doctor"},{"Data":"Person"},{"Data":"Person"},{"Data":"Person"}]}

Comment: Thanks for giving me the point for thought; it was adding multiple values because of wrong method of handling drag event.

Comment: Abbasi maybe you'd want to add your result as an answer here so future seekers of truth will not get too frustrated! Also, @kleopatra (oh what a nose!) if he does add this answer, I'd re-add javafx as a tag as the solution of the problem (though maybe not the problem itself) in this case is very javafx specific. Do you agree?

Comment: @Maverick283 depends on the answer - if it does use fx classes, then yes. the nose, yeah, lol :)